# Can we still use loose CSHTML files in wwwroot in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.Net 4, I could use Razor views as pure CSHTML without tying them to any MVC controller, basically I just wanted the lightweight layout and ability to call server side code when needed.

How do I do that in ASP.Net core? I've placed a CSHTML in wwwroot but the server won't serve it. Is there any particular service or provider I need to add into the startup class?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use _layout file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default controller. not in ASP.NET MVC 4 or Core. But what you can do is to create one. [Simple ASP.NET MVC views without writing a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008970/simple-asp-net-mvc-views-without-writing-a-controller)

But what I'm actually assuming you're asking for is a `.cshtml` page that performs nothing, only HTML and Javascript (and with that make calls to partials, then again you need controllers). If that is what youre after then make a `.html` page in `/wwwroot` and not a `.cshtml` and enable static files in `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
```

and lastly, another thought, I think that you are not after MVC at all but rather ASP.NET Web Pages. By the looks of it the "asp.Net Web Pages" a.k.a loose cshtml looks to be dead in core, but a solution whould be a default controller on it.

Comment: Yeah I'm not after static files, I want to use the centralized layout and other functionality of ASP.Net Web Pages (this is messed up and confusing :P) So it might work if I wire up a default controller? Let me check that out then.

Comment: @Marauderz Then you need a controller, it decides if you wire up the rest by returning `View` or just the content by returnning a `PartialView` from your controller